# plot sipmle chart with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, plot, charts, draw

I need to reproduce the following chart with javascript:
[image]

the red point is variable of course.

I tried with flot lib:

```
var d3 = [[7,7]];

    $.plot("#placeholder", [{
        data: d3,
        points: { show: true }
    }], {
xaxis:
{
  min:-15, max: 15,  tickSize: 5
},

yaxis:
{
    min:-15, max: 15,  tickSize: 5
}
});
```

the result:

[image]

The x-axis is not centered...
i'm looking for a better way to optimize this, to be like my first image, js lib to do this.
Thank you

Comment: an example bellow with D3 library with JSFIDDLE to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lib only, maybe this works for you?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="graph"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#graph
{
  margin; 0 auto;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.tick line
{
  stroke: #59ADEB;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

g path.domain
{
  stroke: #4F4F4F;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Set graph
    var width = 700,
            height = 700,
            padding = 100;

    // create an svg container
    var vis = d3.select("#graph")
    .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([10, -10]).range([width - padding, padding]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-10, 10]).range([height - padding, padding]);

    // define the y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient("left")
            .scale(yScale);

    // define the y axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient("bottom")
            .scale(xScale);

    var xAxisPlot = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height/2) + ")")
            .call(xAxis.tickSize(-height, 0, 0));

    var yAxisPlot = vis.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/2) +",0)")
        .call(yAxis.tickSize(-width, 0, 0));


    xAxisPlot.selectAll(".tick line")
        .attr("y1", (width - (2*padding))/2 * -1)
        .attr("y2", (width - (2*padding))/2 * 1);

    yAxisPlot.selectAll(".tick line")
        .attr("x1", (width - (2*padding))/2 * -1)
        .attr("x2", (width - (2*padding))/2 * 1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szx1eq99/
Uses d3 library.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
`TypeError: d3.scale is undefined[Learn More]`

Comment: have you included the d3 library?

Comment: I tried with:
`https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js`
and it is working. seems that the version v4 of 3d does not know what scale is. 
how can i draw the red point ? :) thanks

Comment: any,  4,5 for example ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/szx1eq99/1/ check this and mark above answer as answer if it helped you please! Forgot to mention this is old code thats why scale did not exist in newer versions..

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a lib, [D3JS](https://d3js.org/) has pretty much every graph style known to man.

Comment: thank you, but I can't find a simple example like my graph in the gallery :)